# jQuery not properly reading CSS "left" property when Chrome is zoomed in?

Tags: jquery

Discovered a strange problem that went undetected because I do 99% of my web dev in Windows.

I've got a neat jQuery-based slider for feature stories on a website. You can see it at http://www.vancitybuzz.com/

I can't seem to figure out why the slider fails on OSX even when using the same version of Chrome. When jQuery reads `$("#slidebox .container").css("left").replace("px","")` it returns `-533` on the first "slide" even though the DOM inspector is actually `-640`.

Is this a jQuery 1.7.1 bug or a Chrome bug? Workaround? Thanks.

### EDIT

I have found what causes this problem. When Chrome v17 is zoomed in (turns out it wasn't OS-specific, only defaults caused by OS) it screws up the real reading of CSS left property. What could be a workaround for this?

You can find the code that controls SlideBox at the bottom here: http://www.vancitybuzz.com/wp-content/themes/meganfox/js/meganfox.js

Comment: same version of chrome + 2 different OSs = inconsistency? sounds like a chrome bug...

Comment: that was my thought, too. i'll see if i can post a workaround

Comment: I'm on OSX / chrome, and it I think it looks correct.

Comment: yeah i don't think i've ever seen "OS sniffing" inside of any library, the only OS-to-OS inconsistency that i've seen occasionally arise is one that is font related, eg. using a specific font that exists by default on one OS and not at all on a different, but even that's kind of an odd case and not at all applicable here... good luck

Comment: @joakimdahlstrom which version of Chrome? using v17.0.963 thx

Comment: @DeLonge, I'm using the exact same one. with .79 at the end as well.

Comment: @joakimdahlstrom that's very strange. macbook, mac desktop, or air? looks like it's only occuring on newer macbook pros but still investigating

Comment: @DeLonge It's supposed to be a few pixels to the left of the white space, right? I'm on a 13" macbook, late 2009 model.

Comment: @joakimdahlstrom check out the edit to my question, i found the cause

Comment: @DeLonge, Oh yeah, I see it. It wanders away out to the left.

Comment: Is this perhaps a CSS pixels vs. Device pixels thing? http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports.html

Comment: I dont want to disappoint you my friend, but the slider is dead in my Firefox 10..

Comment: it's quite possible jQuery is using different methods of pixels, bug report might be needed. @joakimdahlstrom OMG FF10 has been a pain since release!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm rather late to the party here, but I had the exact same problem when I created a slider about a year ago. The workaround I found was to do all of my offsets in percentages instead of pixels. It behaved well in Chrome at all zoom levels after that.

[Flixster](http://www.flixster.com) uses a slider that works in a similar manner, You get stuck, you can learn a lot by dissecting what they do.